# Using Python to extract timestamp text from frame of videos

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, ocr, tesseract

I have a series of videos that contain timestamp in a specific ROI which I have already found. The text can vary between black and white and can mix in the same timestamp. I am struggling to use tesseract to extract the text from some videos, processing as below:

```
roi = (60, 60, 750, 100)  # (x, y, width, height)

# Crop the frame to the ROI
roi_frame = frame[roi[1]:roi[1]+roi[3], roi[0]:roi[0]+roi[2]]

gray_roi_frame = cv2.cvtColor(roi_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


# Gaussian blur
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_roi_frame, (5, 5), 0)

# Canny edge detection
edges = cv2.Canny(blurred, 50, 150, apertureSize=7)

# Display the original image and edges
cv2.imshow('Original Image', gray_roi_frame)
cv2.imshow('Edges', edges)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# OCR on edges frame
extracted_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(edges, lang='eng', config='--psm 6')

print("Extracted Text:", extracted_text)
# Regex for date and time information
date_time_match = re.search(r'(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4} \w+ \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})', extracted_text)
if date_time_match:
    extracted_date_time = date_time_match.group(1)
    print("Extracted Date and Time:", extracted_date_time)
else:
    print("Date and time not found in the extracted text.")
# Release the video capture object
cap.release()
```

Greyscale and canny edge images: [image: Greyscale and canny edge images]

Example grab from clip A:
[Example grab from clip A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKeGb.jpg)
[ROI Frame from clip A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnNhP.png)

Example grab from clip B (This one was easy to extract):
[Example grab from clip B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2D2Ku.jpg)
[ROI Frame from clip B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQg95.png)

Output is essentially garbage:

```
Extracted Text: i ore Wei) is O25
oe aie oF ew ales (Oe)
```

What else could I do to allow OCR to obtain the text accurately given black/white text on a variety of backgrounds?

I have tried canny edge detection, sobel edge detection, adaptive thresholding. Current iteration is clearest visually I've gotten, but OCR is unable to pick up the correct output.

The below seems to be able to obtain each character segmentally, but it includes a few garbage ones and OCR still misreads some "2421167023 Fr ila 02:29". [segmenting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkGHZ.png)

```
# Define the fixed spacing
spacing_x = 32
spacing_y = 60

# Initialize the concatenated symbols list
concatenated_symbols = []
# Define the region of interest (ROI) where the text appears (adjust coordinates as needed)
roi = (60, 80, 750, 100)  # (x, y, width, height)

# Crop the frame to the ROI
roi_frame = frame[roi[1]:roi[1]+roi[3], roi[0]:roi[0]+roi[2]]
# Iterate over the image with the specified spacing
for y in range(0, roi_frame.shape[0] - spacing_y + 1, spacing_y):
    for x in range(0, roi_frame.shape[1] - spacing_x + 1, spacing_x):
        # Extract the symbol ROI
        symbol_roi = roi_frame[y:y+spacing_y, x:x+spacing_x]

        # Convert to grayscale
        gray_roi = cv2.cvtColor(symbol_roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # Apply Gaussian blur to reduce noise
        blurred_roi = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_roi, (5, 5), 0)
         # Apply adaptive thresholding to binarize the image
        _, thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred_roi, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

        # Invert the symbol ROI if needed based on white pixel count
        white_pixel_count = np.count_nonzero(thresh)
        total_pixels = thresh.shape[0] * thresh.shape[1]
        if white_pixel_count < total_pixels / 2:
            thresh = cv2.bitwise_not(thresh)

        # Append the thresholded ROI to the concatenated symbols list
        concatenated_symbols.append(thresh)
        cv2.imshow('symbol', thresh)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
# Concatenate the segmented symbols horizontally
concatenated_symbols = np.hstack(concatenated_symbols)

# Display the concatenated symbols
cv2.imshow('Concatenated Symbols', concatenated_symbols)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: The scale of the two "example grabs" doesn't match the scale of the original image (shown as grayscale). Seems like original symbols fit into consistent 32x42 boxes, whereas in the "grabs" the horizontal spacing is something like 20.75 (and there are additional artifacts). Please, provide proper example inputs in the correct scale. (And I'll see if I feel like playing with it again, so far it was kinda pointless due to the bad examples)

Comment: Anyway, the starting point would be to use the fact that the text is always at the same position, using monospace font, and using the same format, to segment the timestamp region into 23 individual symbols. We can ignore the positions that contain spaces, dashes and colons -- they will always be there. For the remaining positions, each will either contain only one of: digits, upper case or lower case letters. (In fact, the three letter positions will only use the following symbols: `'FMSTW', 'aehoru', 'deintu'`) This could be used to help the OCR by reducing the number of possibilities.

Comment: You'd also try to detect the color of the text on a per-letter basis. Maybe even something as simple as Otsu threshold could be enough with simple heuristics.

Comment: I've edited the post to include ROI coordinates I used, and updated the example grabs to be the entire original frame.

Comment: Well, the ROI seems to match your "Greyscale and canny edge" image... but the scale of the "grabs" still seems weird, and the ROI extracted from them has part of the text cropped off on the left hand side and a lot of wasted space on the right hand side (see [here](https://imgur.com/MLeaQO2)). JPEG also adds some extra noise, which is not helpful. Please, save `roi_frame` immediately after you extract it -- `cv2.imwrite('roi_frame.png', roi_frame)` for example, and make sure that it is 750x100 and upload only that.

Comment: Hmm that's strange, i used imwrite for the grabs. In any case, I have added the roi frames now as pngs

Comment: At this point, I can get something like this: https://i.imgur.com/ihOyclF.png (just the significant symbols binarized and concatenated horizontally). It's getting late, I'll play more tomorrow.

Comment: I use a fixed 32x44 spacing to segment the individual symbols. I ignore those that are fixed. With this spacing, there is a 2 pixel border around each symbol that can be ignored, so I mask it out. I use Otsu threshold followed by `cv2.nonZeroCount` to determine whether to invert particular symbol ROI  (if less than half the pixels are white, invert the symbol ROI). | Honestly, at this point, it seems you don't even need tesseract to make this work, although getting it to perform would need some work. At each position, there are at most 10 possible symbols to pick from.

Comment: just out of curiosity, your result looks quite good, although OCR reads it as: f41420275Fr114902¢79
I have updated the original post with what I tried in terms of attempting your methodology but I was not able to achieve how clean yours looked. How were you able to ignore the irrelevant segments?